# quick fix (java) protocol reconnect

Tags: java, quickfix

I am using quick fix protocol, 
If my log in (start in SocketInitiator) get reject the fix protocol try to connect again and again every 5 sec (using "ReconnectInterval"), 
Is there a way to make the reconnect not in a equal intervals?
for example try to connect three times every 5 SEC and then every 1 MIN?

Comment: Which QuickFIX are you using?  C++, Java, or C#?  (Also note, FIX is the protocol, QuickFIX is an engine for that protocol.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read the sourecode of [AbstractSocketInitiator](http://sourceforge.net/p/quickfixj/code/1113/tree/trunk/core/src/main/java/quickfix/mina/initiator/AbstractSocketInitiator.java#l181) and [SessionSettings](http://sourceforge.net/p/quickfixj/code/1113/tree/trunk/core/src/main/java/quickfix/SessionSettings.java#l734) correctly, you can simply specify the reconnect interval setting with semi-colon separated values:
eg. "5;5;5;60" means, first three retries after 5 seconds, next retries after 60 seconds.

Note: please add links to the used framework, a made just assumption.

Comment: It appears your answer is for QuickFIX/J, the Java port.  I don't know if plain C++ QuickFIX supports this, and I'm pretty sure that QuickFIX/n (C#) doesn't.